# running macos Desktop with broken display on Linux laptop

Tags: macos, display, unix

is there an opportunity to run the Macos  Desktop from my Macbook air  laptop on an ASUS Laptop with a Linux enviroment on it .The problem here is,the display of my Macbook air is broken, so i cannot see the Macos Desktop.
Maybe you have some other solution to see Desktop/work with it.

best regards

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Can't you use an external display? That would definitely be the easiest approach.

Comment: You may have to plug an external display into the Mac to configure it for remote access. Screen Sharing (and Apple remote desktop) are built on and compatible with VNC. So once the necessary services are turned on (in System Preferences > Sharing) you can indeed access the Mac via VNC from a Linux or Windows PC.